# PAPI with CUDA power consumption

Tags: cuda, read-eval-print-loop, papi

I'm trying to measure power consumption on a GPU. First of all I want to know if I can use PAPI to measure power consumption and also I want to know how can I compile CUDA with PAPI code if that's possible.

Comment: It certainly is possible. I personally havent tried it because the PAPI is not getting installed on my system mac os. Compiling shouldnt be a problem just pass the correct library path and the include path to nvcc, you should be good to go. If [that](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/papers/pasa2012/pasa2012_power.pdf) helps.

Answer (score 5):

Nvidia provides a C-based API for monitoring and managing various states of the NVIDIA GPU devices, including the power consumption.

```
nvmlDeviceGetPowerUsage (nvmlDevice_t device, unsigned int* power)
```

Please refer to this link for more info about NVML

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml